# IE and Edge box shadow cut off

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I have a div with some box shadow added to it, however for some reason the shadows are pretty ugly in Internet Explorer and Edge. They all look great on literally every other browser.

[image]

The shadow on the right is from Edge while the shadow on the left is from Chrome.

Here is my css:

```
.container-panel{
    height: 210px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

I have `overflow:visible` on every parent element, however I am setting those attributes from Jquery in `$(document).ready()`, if that does anything.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: For your optional question, you need to distinguish the difference between you knowing something exists and the API knowing something exists.  Consider the example of loading an image into your app with `let image = UIImage(named: "startIcon")!.  This won't crash unless you forgot to include an image named "startIcon" in your resources.  As a programmer, you want this to crash so you don't forget to ship the "startIcon" image with your app.  But it is safe for the user of your app, because the image will be there at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Edge and IE have issues with `box-shadow` when inside tables with `border-collapse` set to `collapse`.

You don't provide the html or the full css so it isn't possible to be more specific about your particular issue.